# Show only those rows where a cell value is bold

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to show just the subtotal rows (which are bolded) and hide everything else. Code crashes when it hits `If c.Value.Font.Bold = False Then`.
Thanks

```
Sub HideEmptyRows() 'quote stack
    
Dim col As String
col = Range("c2").Value    'column to check
Dim sta As Integer
sta = Range("C3").Value    'start row
Dim fin As Integer
fin = Range("C4").Value    'finish row
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range(col & sta & ":" & col & fin)
    
If c.Value.Font.Bold = False Then
c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
Else
c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "crash" mean?  Computer freezes and you have to do a power off reset?  Or perhaps there is some error message that pops up?  If your computer is still active, what is the contents of `col`, `sta` and `fin` at the time of this "crash"?

Comment: `c.Value.Font.Bold` is not valid, try `c.Font.Bold`

Comment: `c.font.bold` fixed it. Thanks Raymond

Comment: @irozak I'm surprised you can even compile the code (I assume). I would expect the compiler to complain about it. Note: Please fully qualify your range or else VBA will assume you are referring to the `ActiveWoorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` range which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

### Show Only 'Bold' Rows

- You can improve performance by turning screen updating off while the rows are being manipulated.
- You can improve performance by hiding the (entire) rows of the complete range and then unhiding the 'bold' rows. You could do it the other way around: show the rows of the complete range and then hide those that are not 'bold' (see the three 'boolean-commented' lines (`False,False,True`)).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HideEmptyRows() 'quote stack
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific

    Dim col As String: col = ws.Range("C2").Value   'column to check
    Dim sta As Long: sta = ws.Range("C3").Value   'start row
    Dim fin As Long: fin = ws.Range("C4").Value   'finish row
        
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(col & sta & ":" & col & fin)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    ' Hide the rows of the complete range.
    rg.EntireRow.Hidden = True ' False
    
    Dim c As Range
    
    ' Show bold rows only.
    For Each c In rg.Cells
        If c.Font.Bold = True Then ' False
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False ' True
        End If
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'MsgBox "Showing only subtotals.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that also works and has sped things up a little. thanks